# Track internal user behviour with google analytics

Tags: lightning, google-analytics, standard

I know that I can add GA code to my visual force pages. Can I do a similar thing to my standard tabs? I have implemented a few processes and I would like to see do my users interact with components as I predicted. I'm using only standard elements cause there is no need for any additional development

Comment: I love the idea but I do not know of any way to do it without custom development. Upvoted the question hoping someone else will have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Google analytics to be added in visualforce and that visualforce can be added as Custom tab.

Standard tab doesnot support this.

If you want external page to be displayed as tab then you have to use Web tab, this us called Mashups.

Otherwise, if you want GA to be exposed in page layout then embed visualforce in page layout.

Comment: do you mean that I need to add a VisualForce component to tab? And in this component, I can implement the GA code?